# iOS Push Notifications not sent for Parse app in production mode

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

I have two Parse apps for a project, one for development and one for production. The production one has "Released in Production" toggled on:

[image: Released in Production]

I am just testing on my phone, nothing has been released and distributed to the App Store.

I am able to send push notifications from the Parse development app:

[image: Pushes Sent is always 1]

But using the exact same settings in the Parse production app (same iOS Development Cert, deviceToken getting saved to an Installation as expected), "Pushes Sent" is always 0:

[image: Pushes Sent is always 0]

I realize that a production cert is needed for Release builds, but as far as I understand, I'm only testing Debug builds (plug in iPhone, click build with physical device as the target), so the only thing that's different when it doesn't work is that it's coming from a Parse app with production mode toggled on.

Am I missing something? Does "Released in Production" have other implications? Could there be something with the app on my phone thinking it's already registered for Push Notifications from Parse development app, so when I try to run it pointing at the Parse production app, it fails?

FYI - this is a React Native app. `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is defined and works when coming from Parse dev, but nothing from Parse prod.

Any suggestions or ideas would be most appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If you click info button in `Release in Production` it'll say, that it's just for Parse knowledge, so they can properly scale they resources allocated for your app. It has nothing to do with Push Notifications.

To test Production certificate try to build your app using `Release` mode.